# Remove the xmlns attribute and rename the root node

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, xml-namespaces

Hi I want to remove the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` namespace from the source xhtml/xml file and rename the root node and would like to try and do this using only one style sheet.  Is this possible?

Here is my example source xml/xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title/>
  <meta/>
</head>

<body link="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0">
<div>
  <p>Here is a paragraph</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my desired output:

```
<document>
  <section>
    <paragraph>Here is a paragraph</paragraph>
  </section>
</document>
```

Currently, I can only achieve this result using two style sheets (see below), but I want to be able to combine these instructions into one style sheet.  Is this possible, and if so, how? Thanks in advance for any help.

Current style sheet 1:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="*|@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
<xsl:apply-templates/>`
</xsl:template>`

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current style sheet 2:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*|@*|text()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="html">
  <document>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
  </document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div">
  <section>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
  </section>`
</xsl:template>`

<xsl:template match="p">
  <paragraph>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
  </paragraph>
</xsl:template>`

<xsl:template match="head"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please fix question formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using XSLT 2.0, all you need to do is add

```
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

to stylesheet 2, and the job is done.

Comment: Thanks, Michael.

Is it possible to do with xslt 1.0?

Comment: Not with one line of code. You will either have to change all the path expressions to add prefixes that match the XHTML namespace, or you'll have to do two passes, one to remove the namespaces. XSLT 1.0 is a pain.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways you could do this. Here is one.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xhtml">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|comment()|processing-instruction()|text()">
  <xsl:copy />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*"><!-- xhtml:html -->
  <document>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xhtml:body">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xhtml:div">
  <section>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </section>`
</xsl:template>`

<xsl:template match="xhtml:p">
  <paragraph>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </paragraph>
</xsl:template>`

<xsl:template match="xhtml:head"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Update**
I forgot to add the xhtml: to the template matches. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

**Just this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" exclude-result-prefixes="x">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <document>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </document>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="x:div">
  <section><xsl:apply-templates/></section>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="x:p">
  <paragraph><xsl:apply-templates/></paragraph>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title/>
        <meta/>
    </head>
    <body link="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0">
        <div>
            <p>Here is a paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<document>
   <section>
      <paragraph>Here is a paragraph</paragraph>
   </section>
</document>
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you and Michael for providing the 2.0 and 1.0 answers to this question.

Comment: Thank you Dimitre providing the 1.0 answer for desired result.

Answer (score 1):

For an xslt 2.0 solution, adding to Michael Kay's earlier answer, the following template will also stop the namespace from being added to child elements of the root element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri() = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml']">
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
<xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```